How to indivdually animate each ik target
so I am trying to animate a 4 legged spider and I wanted two of the ik targets (legs) to move 10 frames ahead of the other two. However, every time I select the two ik targets and move the keyframes (I selected all keyframes and moved them 10 frames up), it does it to all ik targets (legs). I was following this video and everything worked fine until 7:03, please let me know what could be causing this error.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=imbIsNAvUpM&t=308s&ab_channel=Polyfjord

please provide blend file because we have no idea what you did. Just a yt link is nice, but doesn't show what you really did. thx.

You've duplicated the object, by default the action attached to the new object is the same as the original one, the actions are linked, if you modify it, it will also modify the action of the original one. To fix that, open the Dope Sheet, switch it to Action Editor, and create a new action from the existing one:

If you want the duplicated object to have a new action by default, go into the Preferences > Editing > Objects > Copy on Duplicate and enable the Action option:

